# Inquiry on findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, deprecation-warning, strict-mode

I am new to **React** and I recently encountered this warning: **findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.**

Turns out this warning is due to the library I am using which is ***Material UI***. I found a remedy to remove this annoying warning from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220424/material-ui-drawer-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode).

Now don't get me wrong, the solution works like magic but the curious me would like to ask if there might be any side effects that could possibly occur if I do the said solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix ''findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode'' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937037/how-can-i-fix-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-error)